# What is the correct name of this aircraft subsystem in English?

Tags: avionics

I would like to know what the correct name of this aircraft susbsystem is in English:

[image]([Source](http://ntlab-sk.ru/sitefiles/1/10/30085/1.png))

name: пилотажно навигационный комплекс
+/- literally translated it could be something like: flight navigation system.

I am looking for some sort of blockdiagram of this system of either an F-35 (my favorite) or otherwise a boeing airplane. A blockdiagram which components are used and how they communicate with each other. E.g.:

[image]([Source](http://ok-t.ru/studopedia/baza4/700365673196.files/image433.jpg))

Could anybody suggest me some good places to look for?

Comment: Link showing the reverse of the same component: http://ntlab-sk.ru/sitefiles/1/10/30085/2.png

Comment: @JonathanWalters thx for your answer. Do you happen to have a picture from the bottomside of the component? Maybe that will answer one of my questions...

Comment: No, sorry, I do not. That is the only other picture I could find.

Comment: It looks to be some kind of AHRS or IMU, but it is impossible to tell from the images. There seems to be some kind of part number on top, but it isn't clear.

Comment: @RonBeyer I guessed, based on the google translate result, that this was a flight management system. But really not sure though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [product page](http://ntlab-sk.ru/portfolio.htm) and Google translate:

> Newton is designed for use in unmanned aerial vehicles (UAVs), civil and special purpose. Designed to determine the parameters of flight and navigation and automatic flight control UAV, payload control and to ensure information exchange with the ground control station (NPU).
>
> - Support RTK technology for high-precision positioning according to the satellite radio navigation systems (SRNS)
> - The high accuracy of the orientation angle according to the SRNS
> - Possibility of interconnecting with foreign strapdown inertial navigation system (SINS) on the fiber-optic gyro (FOG)
> - Possibility of controlling any types of payloads including mode gyrostabilization
> - Available in a block of flight and navigation built-in radio for transmission of telemetry and control commands
> - The presence in the radio unit built ground goniometric RTK-receiver of the SRNS signals

It's an FMS ([Flight Management System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_management_system)) with a capability to connect to an [INS](http://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Inertial_Navigation_System_(INS)).

---

As for diagrams for the F-35, the general public doesn't know what the F-35 cockpit looks like, let alone schematics for avionics.

Comment: If you go on a flight sim forum they might have an idea on Boeing fms. Some people go to great lengths to make their sims as accurate as possible